# Why the images of the publications are altered at the moment that I make a new publication with images?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

[image: the pictures on the second post are wrong]

when I reload browser I can see the post's pics

[image: pics updated when reload browser]

I have a component referring to the posts, but when you make a post that contains images, they are not updated and the post remains with the images from the previous post, the only way to prevent this from happening is by updating the browser and it should not be like that

Could someone help me to know what is happening, if I should update the component when loading the images or what should I do?

Thanks!

fomPost.vue =>

```
<template>
    <div class="card bg-dark border-left-primary border-right-primary shd mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div v-if="status_msg" :class="{ 'alert-green': status, 'alert-danger': !status }" class="alert"
                 role="alert">{{ status_msg }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="content-body" class="form-control" v-model="body"></textarea>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-lg float-right" data-toggle="tooltip"
                   data-title="Agregar imágenes" data-placement="bottom" @click="toggle()">
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div v-show="isOpen" :style="'margin-top: 2rem'">
                <div class="uploader"
                     @dragenter="OnDragEnter"
                     @dragleave="OnDragLeave"
                     @dragover.prevent
                     @drop="onDrop"
                     :class="{ dragging: isDragging }">

                    <div class="upload-control" v-show="images.length">
                        <label for="file">Agregar más imágenes</label>
                    </div>


                    <div v-show="!images.length">
                        <p>Arrastra las imágenes ó</p>
                        <div class="file-input">
                            <label for="file">Selecciónalas</label>
                            <input type="file" id="file" @change="onInputChange"
                                   accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" multiple>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="images-preview" v-show="images.length">
                    <div class="img-wrapper" v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
                        <div class="thumbnail" :style="`background-image: url(${image.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm)})`">
                            <div class="options">
                                <div>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-light" uk-tooltip="title: Eliminar"
                                       @click="removeimage(index)">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-light" uk-tooltip="title: Previsualizar"
                                       uk-toggle="target: #modal-media-image" @click="showImage(image)">
                                        <i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <span class="size" v-text="getFileSize(files[index].size)"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="modal-media-image" class="uk-flex-top" uk-modal>
                            <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-width-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">
                                <button class="uk-modal-close-outside" type="button" uk-close></button>
                                <img width="1024px" :src="dialogImageUrl">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-opacity-7-dark">
            <button type="button" @click="createPost" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
                <template v-if="isCreatingPost" class="align-items-center">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="mr-1">Publicando</span>
                        <div class="loadingio-spinner-dual-ring-botj7pu8xqc">
                            <div class="ldio-ifliw7yncz">
                                <div></div>
                                <div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                    Publicar
                </template>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: "FormPostText",
        props: ['profile'],
        data() {
            return {
                dialogImageUrl: "",
                dialogVisible: false,
                isDragging: false,
                dragCount: 0,
                files: [],
                images: [],
                status_msg: "",
                status: "",
                isCreatingPost: false,
                title: "",
                body: "",
                isOpen: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            $("#content-body").emojioneArea({
                placeholder: "¿Qué estás pensando?",
                searchPlaceholder: "Buscar",
                buttonTitle: "Usa la tecla [TAB] para insertarlos más rápido",
                pickerPosition: 'bottom',
                filtersPosition: "bottom",
                searchPosition: "top"
            });
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
                create: "post/makePost"
            }),

            showImage(file) {
                this.dialogImageUrl = file;
                this.dialogVisible = true;
            },
            OnDragEnter(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                this.dragCount++;
                this.isDragging = true;
                return false;
            },
            OnDragLeave(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.dragCount--;
                if (this.dragCount <= 0)
                    this.isDragging = false;
            },
            onInputChange(e) {
                const files = e.target.files;
                Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));
            },
            onDrop(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                this.isDragging = false;
                const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
                Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));
            },
            addImage(file) {
                const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;

                if (!isLt2M) {
                    this.showNotification("La imágen no puede ser mayor a 2MB.");
                    return;
                }

                if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                    this.showNotification(`${file.name} no es una imágen`);
                    return;
                }

                this.files.push(file);

                const img = new Image(), reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (e) => this.images.push(e.target.result);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                return isLt2M;
            },
            removeimage: function (index) {
                this.images.splice(index, 1);
            },
            getFileSize(size) {
                const fSExt = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'];
                let i = 0;

                while (size > 900) {
                    size /= 1024;
                    i++;
                }
                return `${(Math.round(size * 100) / 100)} ${fSExt[i]}`;
            },
            toggle() {
                this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
            },
            createPost() {
                var body = $("#content-body").val();
                var text = emojione.toImage(body);

                if (!this.validateForm()) {
                    return false;
                }

                this.isCreatingPost = true;

                const formData = new FormData();

                formData.append("user", this.profile.uid);
                formData.append("body", text);

                this.files.forEach(file => {
                    formData.append('images[]', file, file.name);
                });

                this.create(formData).then((res) => {
                    if (res.data.status === 0) {
                        this.status = code;
                        this.showNotification(res.data.msg);
                    }

                    document.querySelector(".emojionearea-editor").innerHTML = '';

                    this.isCreatingPost = false;
                    this.images = [];
                    this.files = [];
                    this.isOpen = false;

                    let post = res.data;

                    this.$emit("new", post);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.isCreatingPost = false;
                });
            },
            validateForm() {
                if (!$("#content-body").val()) {
                    this.status = false;
                    this.showNotification("Debes escribir algo para publicar...");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
            showNotification(message) {
                this.$swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    html: message
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Post.vue =>

```
<template>
    <div id="timeline">
        <div v-if="authenticated.username === username || isFriend">
            <FormPost :profile="profile" @new="addPostText"></FormPost>
        </div>
        <!--<pre>{{postsArr}}</pre>-->
        <div v-if="postsCount > 0">
            <div v-for="(post, index) in postsArr" :key="index">
                <div class="cardbox shadow-lg bg-opacity-5-dark shd">
                    <div class="cardbox-heading">
                        <div class="dropdown float-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-circle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                    data-boundary="window">
                                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-scale dropdown-menu-right" role="dropdown">
                                <template v-if="post.user.id === user.uid || post.friend.id === user.uid">
                                    <b-dropdown-item href="javascript:void(0)" @click="deletePost(post.post.id, index)">
                                        <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon:  trash"></span> Eliminar
                                    </b-dropdown-item>
                                    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
                                </template>
                                <b-dropdown-item href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <span class="uk-margin-small-right text-danger" uk-icon="icon:  warning"></span>
                                    Reportar
                                </b-dropdown-item>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media m-0">
                            <div class="d-flex mr-3">
                                <a v-bind:href="post.user.username">
                                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" v-bind:src="post.friend.photo" alt="User">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <p class="m-0"><a v-bind:href="post.friend.username">{{ '@' + post.friend.username }}</a></p>
                                <small><span><i
                                    class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ since(post.post.created_at) }}</span></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cardbox-item">
                        <p class="mx-4">{{ post.post.body | setEmoji }}</p>
                        <div v-if="post.images.length > 0">
                            <!--<photo-grid
                                :box-height="'600px'"
                                :box-width="'100%'"
                                :boxBorder="0"
                                :excess-text="'+ {{count}} imágenes'"
                                uk-lightbox="animation: slide"
                            >
                                <img v-for="(imahe, index) in post.images" v-bind:src="`http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/${post.friend.id}/${imahe.url}`" :key="index"/>
                            </photo-grid>-->
                            <ImagesGrid :images="post.images" :idFriend="post.friend.id"
                                        uk-lightbox="animation: slide"></ImagesGrid>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cardbox-base">
                        <ul class="float-right">
                            <li><a><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a><em class="mr-5">{{ post.comments_count || comments_count }}</em></a></li>
                            <li><a><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a><em class="mr-3">03</em></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Likes :postid="post.post.id" :user="user"></Likes>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img
                                src="http://www.themashabrand.com/templates/bootsnipp/post/assets/img/users/3.jpeg"
                                class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="User"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img
                                src="http://www.themashabrand.com/templates/bootsnipp/post/assets/img/users/1.jpg"
                                class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="User"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img
                                src="http://www.themashabrand.com/templates/bootsnipp/post/assets/img/users/5.jpg"
                                class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="User"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img
                                src="http://www.themashabrand.com/templates/bootsnipp/post/assets/img/users/2.jpg"
                                class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="User"></a></li>
                            <li><a><span>242 Likes</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <CommentsPost
                        @new="commentsCount"
                        :postid="post.post.id"
                        :postuserid="user.uid"
                        :user="user"
                    ></CommentsPost>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="pagination-outer">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item" :class="[pagination.current_page > 1 ? '' : 'disabled']">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item" v-for="page in pagesNumber" :class="[page == isActived ? 'active' : '']">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" v-bind:data-hover="page" @click.prevent="changePage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item" :class="[pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page ? '' : 'disabled']">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" aria-label="Next" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div v-else class="card bg-opacity-5-dark mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span class="text-light">No tiene posts aún.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    var moment = require("moment");
    moment.locale("es");

    import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    import FormPost from "../Posts/FormPost";
    import Likes from "../Posts/Likes";
    import CommentsPost from "../Posts/CommentsPost";
    import ImagesGrid from "../Posts/ImagesGrid";

    export default {
        name: "Posts",
        props: {
            username: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            profile: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            user: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            isFriend: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                page: 0,
                offset: 4,
                comments_count: ''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getPosts();
        },
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
            this.getPosts()
            next()
        },
        beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
            this.getPosts()
            next()
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                authenticated: "auth/authenticated",
                postsArr: "post/postsLists",
                pagination: "post/postsPagination",
                postsCount: "post/postsCount"
            }),

            isActived: function() {
                return this.pagination.current_page;
            },

            pagesNumber: function () {
                if(!this.pagination.to) {
                    return [];
                }

                var from = this.pagination.current_page - this.offset;

                if(from < 1) {
                    from = 1;
                }

                var to = from + (this.offset * 2);

                if(to >= this.pagination.last_page) {
                    to = this.pagination.last_page;
                }

                var pagesArray = [];

                while(from <= to) {
                    pagesArray.push(from);
                    from++;
                }

                return pagesArray;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
                getPostsByUser: "post/fetchPosts",
                removePost: "post/deletePost",
            }),

            async getPosts(page) {
                await this.getPostsByUser(page);
                await this.$forceUpdate();
            },

            async addPostText(post) {
                await this.postsArr.unshift(post);
                await this.$forceUpdate();
                await this.changePage(1);
            },

            since(d) {
                return moment(d).fromNow();
            },

            commentsCount(count) {
                this.comments_count = count;
            },

            deletePost(post, index) {
                this.postsArr.splice(index, 1)
                this.removePost(post)
            },

            changePage(page) {
                this.pagination.current_page = page;
                this.getPosts(page);
            }
        },
        filters: {
            setEmoji: (value) => {
                var rx = /<img\s+(?=(?:[^>]*?\s)?class="[^">]*emojione)(?:[^>]*?\s)?alt="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(?:[^<]*<\/img>)?/gi;

                return value.replace(rx, "$1")
            }
        },
        components: {
            FormPost,
            Likes,
            CommentsPost,
            ImagesGrid
        },
        watch: {
            '$route': 'getPosts'
        }
```

ImagesGrid.vue =>

```
<template>
    <photo-grid
        :box-height="'600px'"
        :box-width="'100%'"
        :boxBorder="0"
        :excess-text="'+ {{count}} imágenes'"
        uk-lightbox="animation: slide"
    >
        <a :href="`http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/${idFriend}/${imahe.url}`"
           v-for="(imahe, index) in images"
           v-bind:data-image="`http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/${idFriend}/${imahe.url}`"
           :key="index">
        </a>
    </photo-grid>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['idFriend', 'images'],
        watch: {
            $route(to, from, next) {
                this.$forceUpdate();
                next()
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Post.js =>

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './index'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        posts: [],
        posts_count : 0,
        pagination: {
            'total': 0,
            'current_page': 0,
            'per_page': 0,
            'last_page': 0,
            'from': 0,
            'to': 0,
        }
    },
    getters: {
        postsLists(state) {
            return state.posts;
        },

        postsCount(state) {
            return state.posts_count
        },

        postsPagination(state) {
            return state.pagination
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_POST_COLLECTION (state, data) {
            state.posts = data.posts.data ;
            state.pagination = data.paginate;
            state.posts_count = data.paginate.total;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        makePost({commit,dispatch}, data) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post('user/post/create', data)
                    .then((response) => {
                        dispatch("fetchPosts", 1)
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
            })
        },

        fetchPosts({commit}, page) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(`user/${store.state.user.profile.username}/posts?page=${page}`)
                    .then((response) => {
                        //console.log(response.data.posts.data);
                        commit('SET_POST_COLLECTION', response.data);

                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
            })
        },

        deletePost({commit}, id) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let params = {'id': id};

                axios.post('user/post/delete', params)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data)
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
            })
        },

        createComment({commit}, comment) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post('user/post/comment/create', comment)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data)
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need some code or something to actually fix your problem

Comment: I've edited the post, thank u